# Pandas MultiIndex from regex on column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, multi-index

I have a pandas dataframe that looks

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['JoeSmith', 5],
        ['CathySmith', 3],
        ['BrianSmith', 12],
        ['MarySmith', 67],
        ['JoeJones', 23],
        ['CathyJones', 98],
        ['BrianJones', 438],
        ['MaryJones', 75],
        ['JoeCollins', 56],
        ['CathyCollins', 125],
        ['BrianCollins', 900],
        ['MaryCollins', 321],
    ], columns = ['Name', 'Value']
)

print df

            Name  Value
0       JoeSmith      5
1     CathySmith      3
2     BrianSmith     12
3      MarySmith     67
4       JoeJones     23
5     CathyJones     98
6     BrianJones    438
7      MaryJones     75
8     JoeCollins     56
9   CathyCollins    125
10  BrianCollins    900
11   MaryCollins    321
```

The first column 'Name' needs to be split into First and Last names and put into a MultiIndex.

```
               Value
Joe   Smith        5
Cathy Smith        3
Brian Smith       12
Mary  Smith       67
Joe   Jones       23
Cathy Jones       98
Brian Jones      438
Mary  Jones       75
Joe   Collins     56
Cathy Collins    125
Brian Collins    900
Mary  Collins    321
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for extracting `Names` and `surname`, then [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and last [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) column `Name`:

```
df[['name','surname']] = df.Name.str.extract(r'([A-Z][a-z]*)([A-Z][a-z]*)', expand=True)
df = df.set_index(['name','surname']).drop('Name', axis=1)
print df
               Value
name  surname       
Joe   Smith        5
Cathy Smith        3
Brian Smith       12
Mary  Smith       67
Joe   Jones       23
Cathy Jones       98
Brian Jones      438
Mary  Jones       75
Joe   Collins     56
Cathy Collins    125
Brian Collins    900
Mary  Collins    321
```

Comment: This is the better answer

Comment: @piRSquared - Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

```
import pandas as pd

pattern = r'.*\b([A-Z][a-z]*)([A-Z][a-z]*)\b.*'
names = df.Name.str.extract(pattern, expand=True)
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(names.values.tolist())
df.index = midx
df[['Value']]
```

## Explanation

`pattern` grabs a group of letters that starts with a capital `A-Z` followed by any number of lower-case `a-z` followed by another capital `A-Z` and any number of lower-case `a-z`.  Then it splits it into two.

`pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples` creates the `MultiIndex`.

`names.values.tolist()` turns the converted `DataFrame` into a list of lists that will be interpreted as tuples.